# Android Logcat is very short

Tags: android, logcat

I am experiencing a strange issue. 
I am trying to collect some logs from my android phone using [logcollector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&feature=search_result) or [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result). Everything works just fine for my Nexus S and moto Defy but when I am trying to capture and send a log from Galaxy S the output is very very short. It captures only last few seconds of phone's activity.

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Regards, Peter

Comment: I have the same thing happening on a Sumsung Galaxy S3... haven't tried adb yet because I don't have the device :/

Answer (score 0):

Many possible things can be occurring here. Another process could be clearing the logcat buffer periodically (logcat -c).  Galaxy S could have also modified the default buffer size for its logs to be very small (so it is constantly rolling them over).  Other than that, who knows what it could be. The best I can think is to enable USB debugging and seeing if you can run logcat yourself and see what you can see (adb logcat). If you can see the logs fine then it is the app otherwise the system does not allow log collection.

Answer (score 0):

use pipeline to save logs in text file from command prompt

adb logcat > logs.txt

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Anyway that won't solve my problem because the device is being keept by a tester who is not familiar with android SDK :/